# Ranking Values of data frame excluding same dates

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with Dates and Values:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate) 

df<-tibble(DateTime=ymd(c("2018-01-01","2018-01-01","2018-01-02","2018-01-02","2018-01-03","2018-01-03")),
              Value=c(5,10,12,3,9,11),Rank=rep(0,6))
```

I would like to Rank the values of the two last rows, each compared with the rest four Value rows (the ones of previous dates).

I have managed to do this:

```
dfReference<-df%>%filter(DateTime!=max(DateTime))

dfTarget<-df%>%filter(DateTime==max(DateTime))

for (i in 1:nrow(dfTarget)){
  tempDf<-rbind(dfReference,dfTarget[i,])%>%
    mutate(Rank=rank(Value,ties.method = "first"))
  dfTarget$Rank[i]=filter(tempDf,DateTime==max(df$DateTime))$Rank
}
```

Desired output:

```
> dfTarget
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  DateTime   Value  Rank
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 2018-01-03     9     3
2 2018-01-03    11     4
```

But I am looking for a more delicate way.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically the same idea as your `for` loop, but instead of a loop it uses `map_int`, and instead of creating a new data frame using `rbind` it creates a new vector with `c()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

is.max <- with(df,  DateTime == max(DateTime))

df[is.max,] %>% 
  mutate(Rank = map_int(Value, ~
    c(df$Value[!is.max], .x) %>% 
      rank(ties.method = 'first') %>% 
      tail(1)))



# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   DateTime   Value  Rank
#   <date>     <dbl> <int>
# 1 2018-01-03     9     3
# 2 2018-01-03    11     4
```